# Scraping in python using regex not giving any result?

Tags: python, regex

I am using python 3 to scrape a website and print a value. Here is the code

```
import urllib.request
import re

url = "http://in.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=spy"  
hfile = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
htext = hfile.read().decode('utf-8')
regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_SPY">(.+?)</span>'
code = re.compile(regex)
price = re.findall(code,htext)
print (price)
```

when i run this snippet, it prints an empty list, ie. `[]`, but i am expecting a value e.g. `483.33`.

What is the thing that i am getting wrong ? Help

Comment: Please, _please_ don't use regex for parsing HTML. Use (`*gasp!*`) an HTML parser.

Comment: Matt, why can't we use regex ? whats the issue

Comment: its not that you CANT use it, its just that there are WAAAAY better premade, built-in tools already for parsing this type of thing. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?lq=1) post out

Comment: @user2762289 in the sourcecode of the webpage you're trying to scrap, "spy" is in lowercase while you're using uppercase, you need to match case insensitive or make everything lowercase.

Comment: @HamZa Case Sensitive is not an issue, because the webpage automatically converts it into lowercase. Output is not changed even when i use lowercase SPY.

Comment: @user2762289 lolwut, please don't tell me that `spy === SPY`. Also why do you think you could set the `i` modifier ? I'm talking about `<span id="yfs_l84_spy">(.+?)</span>`, you're using `<span id="yfs_l84_SPY">(.+?)</span>`

Comment: You know that there is a Yahoo Finance API?

Comment: @HamZa. You are absolutely correct !!! This issue is solved by changing SPY to lowercase. Thank you So much for your support.

Comment: actually you **can't** parse arbitrary HTML/XML with regular expression because it isn't a regular language. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Parsing html with regexes can only result in a downvote.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson regular expressions are no longer "regular" in some flavors. See the [power of modern regex](http://nikic.github.io/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html) or see [this awesome answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/).

Comment: @HamZa I qualified it with ***arbitrary***, and none of the flavors of regex I know of support that.

Answer (score 2):

I have to recommend that you not use regex to parse HTML, because [HTML is not a regular language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2581969).  Yes, you *could* use it here.  It's not a good habit to get into.

The biggest issue I imagine that you're having is that the *real* `id` of the `span` you're looking for on that page is `yfs_l84_spy`.  Note case.

That said, here is a quick implementation in [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://in.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=spy"  
hfile = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
htext = hfile.read().decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(htext)
soup.find('span',id="yfs_l84_spy")
Out[18]: <span id="yfs_l84_spy">176.12</span>
```

And to get at that number:

```
found_tag = soup.find('span',id="yfs_l84_spy") #tag is a bs4 Tag object
found_tag.next #get next (i.e. only) element of the tag
Out[36]: '176.12'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will switch over :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the regex correctly, there are 2 ways of doing this:

1.

```
regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_spy">(.+?)</span>'
code = re.compile(regex)
price = code.findall(htext)
```

2.

```
regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_spy">(.+?)</span>'
price = re.findall(regex, htext)
```

It should be noted that the Python regex library does some caching internally so precaching has only limited effect.

Comment: I tried both ways but the result is still the same, An Empty list.

Comment: In that case your regex simply isn't matching. This could be pretty much anything, an extra space, capital letters versus lowercase, multiple lines... etc